# Fatal error, is run_query a function?

Tags: php, mysql, fatal-error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function run_query() on null in /home/matrixhub/public_html/login.php:64
>   Stack trace:
>    #0 {main} thrown in /home/matrixhub/public_html/login.php on line 64

I thought `run_query` was a function but alright. The following is line 57 to 79:

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

    $name = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];


    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$email'";
    $result = $obj->run_query($query);
    if ($count = mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $row = $result->fetch_object();
        if (password_verify($password, $row->password)) {
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $name;
            echo "Logged in";
        } else {
            echo "Not logged in";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Your username or password is incorrect!')</script>";
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no php function `run_query`

Comment: To help you save face in the future, always search a function name `php.net run_query` ... `php.net fetch_object` ...

Comment: Use `mysqli_query()` instead of `$obj->run_query()`..

Comment: Where do you set `$obj`? The error message is very clear that `$obj == null`

Comment: While there might not be a PHP native function `run_query`, we don't know what `$obj` is - could you post the code where that variable is defined?

Comment: I did not set an $obj why?

Comment: The error message is not about `run_query()`. It is about invoking `run_query()` as a method of `$obj` that is not an object. Most probably `$obj` is `null` (not set) or `false`. Where is it initialized?

Comment: It isn’t set, what do I set $obj to? I followed a tutorial for this login form because I don’t understand the whole query things